# with httpclient is there a way to get the character set of the page with a HEAD request?

Tags: java, httpclient

I'm doing a basic HEAD request using httpclient library. I'm curious how I'd be able to get the character set that apache returns E.g.: utf-8, iso-8859-1, etc...
thanks!

```
  HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
  HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 2000);
  HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 2000);

  DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
  httpclient.getParams().setParameter("http.useragent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)");

  HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
  httpget = new HttpHead(url); 

  HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget, localContext);

  this.sparrowResult.statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

WORKING RESULT UPDATED

```
Header contentType = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Type");
String charset= contentType.getValue();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in HTTP 1.1, the character set is in the Content-Type Header

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

So that should be buried in

```
HttpResponse.Headers
```

So, this should work

```
HttpResponse.Headers.["Content-Type"]
```

** didnt test this, but you get the idea

Answer (score 19):

If using HttpClient 4.2

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;

ContentType contentType = ContentType.getOrDefault(entity);
Charset charSet = contentType.getCharset();
```

Answer (score 4):

If using HttpClient 4.1 (latest):

```
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

String charset = EntityUtils.getContentCharSet(entity);
if (charset == null) {
    charset = HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET;
}
```

Comment: FYI - `getContentCharSet` is deprecated now.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases the server will not give you the charset in the header but its written in the content, e.g. this url: http://seniv.dlmostil.ru/jacket/p/kupit-sportivnie-bryki-adidas-s-dostavkoy/

When you do

```
ContentType contentType = ContentType.getOrDefault(entity); 
Charset charSet = contentType.getCharset();
```

then charSet is **null**.

In that case I read the stream and try to extract the charSet from the html code with a regular expression, so when you read the content from the input stream into

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
```

then you can do this:

```
String help = new String(out.toByteArray());
Pattern charSet = Pattern.compile("charset\\s*=\\s*\"?(.*?)[\";\\>]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = charSet.matcher(help);
String encoding = m.find() ? m.group(1).trim() : "UTF-8";
if (Charset.availableCharsets().get(encoding) == null) encoding = Charsets.UTF_8.toString();
String html = new String(out.toByteArray(), encoding);
```

I hope you get the idea of this last exit when all the other methods won't work.