# Newly-developed encoding issue with an Oracle Java program

Tags: java, netbeans, encoding, httprequest, apache-commons-httpclient

My Java program (or rather, a part of it) sends a request to a webservice and receives rdf-strings including ancient Greek words in unicode. I wrote the program in netbeans and so far, there has not been a problem during run-time, both in the netbeans environment and outside as a standalone jar under Linux and Windows XP. Now, all of a sudden the Greek words in the rdf come back garbled like this:

> á¼€

At first, I thought this was a Windows XP problem, but when checking under Windows 7 the problem persisted. I found out that I was running OpenJDK under Linux, and was since able to reproduce the issue using Oracle Java.
This is the relevant code (of course, I may have tunnel vision, so please tell me if you need more):

```
try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get;
        get = new HttpGet(URL+URLEncoder.encode(form, "UTF-8"));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
        if (201 == response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()) {
            HttpEntity respEnt = response.getEntity();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(respEnt.getContent()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            char[] cbuffer = new char[256];
            int read;

            while ((read = reader.read(cbuffer)) != -1) {
                sb.append(cbuffer,0,read);
            }
            //System.out.println(sb.toString());
            rdf = new String(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-8");

        } else {
            System.err.println("HTTP Request fehlgeschlagen.");
        }         

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Problem beim HTTP Request.");
    }
```

The webservice is the Perseus morphology service, it can be found here: http://services.perseids.org/bsp/morphologyservice/analysis/word?lang=grc&engine=morpheusgrc&word=. Try "word=μῆνιν", for example. How or when the rdf is generated, I really don't know.

I would be very grateful for further insights!

Comment: When did you notice this occurring? I thought XP hasn't gotten any updates recently, save for that one IE security update. Does it happen with other versions of Windows?

Comment: I first noticed it on April 4th, so just before the end of the XP lifecycle. I have been trying to solve this on my own for the last month or so. Unfortunately, I do not have other versions of Windows at hand!

Comment: Ah, I see. Have you tried messing with the encodings and seeing if you can get something other than gibberish? And have you verified that the bytes you're getting back from the server are the same on all the machines you tried? Also, if you're willing to trust an internet stranger I could try your code on Windows 7 sometime later today too.

Comment: I do get other things than gibberish, the rest of the rdf string is just fine. How would I go about verifying the bytes? Do you think they change depending on from where they are called?
Thanks for offering to try the code, however, I'll be able to check out a Windows 7 machine tomorrow with a colleague!

Comment: Oh, so it's just the Greek that's messed up? You might be able to verify bytes by using a `BufferedInputStream` and the [read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#read(byte[], int, int)) to read into a byte array, which you can then print to see exactly what you're getting. I'm not really sure whether what you get back will change depending on the machine you get a response from, but this way you can at least be sure that if the message you receive is the same, then it's not the server doing something wonky. I wouldn't call it a necessary step though.

Comment: I doubt that the bytes would differ significantly though, if the rest of the string is OK, and assuming the server doesn't distinguish between machines (under most cases it won't, I believe, since all it sees is an HTTP request and not any information about the request's origin (I think)). Could you perhaps try a second XP machine, if you have access to one? Did you make any software upgrades around that time?

Comment: There's [this page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin), but it seems to only show security updates that I don't believe would affect character display...

Comment: Thank you very much for your input! I did some further checking and indeed encountered the same problem on Windows 7. I then remembered, finally, that ubuntu runs OpenJDK per default, and was able to reproduce the issue under Linux when using Oracle Java. This is were it gets weird, though: at some point during runtime, the output was suddenly clear again, and when starting the program the next time, there was no gibberish. I am now off to do further tests on Windows XP.

Comment: Interesting... So perhaps it seems like something with Oracle's runtime?  The output changing from one run to the next does seem rather off though. Are you sure that the server is returning the same response every time? The runtime itself producing two different outputs on two consecutive runs doesn't seem like it should be possible for a program, as programs *should* run deterministically...

Comment: So... I have now tried to run the program under Windows with the Java versions 7_55,7_51 and 7_45, but no change so far. I'm currently at a loss and should probably go and review my code again.

Comment: could you provide more details on the server side, please:
* Where does it read the rdf-strings from? (say files, database or are the generated on the fly)

Comment: And could you please post the webservice method that sends the response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the encoding of your strings is consistent from client to server and back again. In your case of course the servers response (rdf-strings) is most important (encoding serveside, decoding in your client code).

One thing concerning the client code you posted :
You are using the one argument constructor of InputStreamReader in this line:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(respEnt.getContent()));
```

It will read from the inputstream using the VM (and systems) default charset, so the outcome will depend on the machine/VM you are running your client application on.
Try explicitly setting the charset using this constructor

```
new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8")
```

See also [API-doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html).

Search your code for more uses of the one argument constructor of both *InputStreamReader* and *OutputStreamWriter*, which also uses the default encoding.

If you have no control over the server code (the webservice implementation), you can try to find out the answers charset like this:

```
Header contentType = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Type");
String charset= contentType.getValue();
```

(This is from the apache HttpClient API you seem to be using).
see also [this Q on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216730/with-httpclient-is-there-a-way-to-get-the-character-set-of-the-page-with-a-head).

Comment: I hadn't thought about that... Does the default charset differ between OpenJDK and Oracle's implementation though?

Comment: @user3580294 the locale can be set by the user on each computer, this locale will determine the default charset used by the system.

Comment: @RossBille I'm aware of that, but considering the issues that OP is having, I'm not totally sure that that is the problem. Seems like the program used to work on Windows until something broke it some time ago, and from what I know Windows doesn't randomly change its default charset. Not to mention OP's comment where the program's output changed from run to run, but that could be an anomaly...

Comment: @user3580294 changing the JDK impl is potentially affecting many things on different "levels" I guess. At first glance both impls seem to pick up the charset and default encoding from the OS and can be influenced by system properties e.g. "-Dfile.encoding".

Comment: @ithofm I suppose... Guess we'll have to see whether it solves OP's problem. There are still a few things that I find strange, like how different runs of the program seem to give different results, that make me want to think that encoding might not be the issue (or not the only issue)...

Comment: The explicit InputStreamReader solved the problem indeed, thank you very much! It appears that the webservice changed something, they are a bit unreliable in that way (I'm adding it to the question for future reference). The anomaly under Linux remains a mystery, though: I could not reproduce the garbled output, and everything is the same each time I run the program. I'm willing to let it go for the moment, as the people using the program are running it under Windows. In any case, thank you very much, all of you!