# some unknown chars after HttpGet execution - ANDROID

Tags: android, url, character-encoding, http-get

i have googled for hours, checking stackoverflow posts for hours but no result :

my code is :

```
    String result = null;
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("some site here");
    request.addHeader("Content-Type","text/html; charset=iso-8859-15");
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(request);
        BufferedReader in;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
    String line = "";
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    in.close();
    result = sb.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but after printing the content of the String result (my page) in the picture below, two french chars ( é & è) were not recognized  :

[image]

NB : these chars are well recognized by the browser

how to solve this problem please ?
thank you

Comment: You need to specify a charset when creating `InputStreamReader`. Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216730/with-httpclient-is-there-a-way-to-get-the-character-set-of-the-page-with-a-head

Comment: even if i have specified the Type content : 
request.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8"); the problem persists

Comment: The request doesn't matter, you need to check what the encoding is of the *response*.

Comment: The response encoding is : charset=iso-8859-15 , i've already set that in the header but same result => �l�ves

Comment: `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "ISO-8859-15"));`

Comment: thanx a lotttttttttt, the problem is solved